# How do I pronounce the combination of a regnal name/number and a dynasty name?

Tags: pronunciation, pronunciation-vs-spelling, names

I know how to pronounce a regnal name with a regnal number after it, like Elizabeth I ("Elizabeth the First") or Charles IV ("Charles the Fourth"). But sometimes I see the regnal name/number followed by a dynasty name, like [Elizabeth II Windsor](http://delong.typepad.com/sdj/2012/01/the-british-economy-is-now-doing-worse-than-it-did-in-the-great-depression.html) or [Nicholas II Romanov](http://russia-ic.com/people/general/n/216). There are also similar names that seem to be honorific, like [Antiochus IV Epiphanes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antiochus_IV_Epiphanes) or [Ptolemy VI Philometor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ptolemy_VI_Philometor), although maybe that's just a Greek thing.

My question is, how do I say these names when speaking aloud? For example, is Elizabeth II Windsor pronounced:

- Elizabeth the Second Windsor?
- Elizabeth the Second of Windsor?
- Elizabeth the Second of House Windsor?
- Elizabeth Windsor the Second?

Does the answer vary for different monarchies? Do honorific names like Antiochus IV Epiphanes work the same way?

Comment: I have never seen the present (or any other king or queen) British monarch referred to as *Elizabeth II Windsor* in my life. Nor do I recognise the web-site - looks an odd sort of article to me.

Comment: @WS2 It seems to pop up a lot on genealogy pages. Here's one: http://europeandynasties.com/Descendants_of_ElizabethIIi_Windsor.htm

Comment: It's an unusual formulation, and hence sounds odd, but there can be nothing wrong with 'Elizabeth the Second, of the House of Windsor'. Though 'Elizabeth the Second, Elizabeth Windsor' may be unacceptable because of the preference of the Queen (title vs name and acceptable ways to show these). This now becomes not an English language question per se, but a question about etiquette. Like 'Should it be _Lloyd's_ or _Lloyds_?' With the historic examples, choose a history professor. 'Antiochus the fourth  (Epiphanes)' or 'Antiochus the fourth (Antiochus Epiphanes)' suggest themselves.

Comment: @AdamHaun For all I know it could be some 10-year-old kid's homework. You do see the daftest things on the internet.

Comment: @AdamHaun The author of the site you've referenced in your comment is not English, and it's possible that he is therefore using incorrect British 'terminology' in the way he has written some of the names of British Monarchs.

Answer (score 1):

From an English perspective I have not come across this notation.  However, the British monarchy do not have surnames per say, but rather belong to a "house".

If I had to speak this statement I would probably say:

Elizabeth the Second **of the** Royal House of Windsor.